# Heavy head after running

Tags: running

Twice now, I've had the phenomenom that after a running competition, my head has gone very heavy and woozy. Its kindof hard to describe, but it sortof feels like needlepricks in my forehead, along with bigtime sweating and a general woozyness.

It does get somewhat better when I'm in a well-ventilated area (like outside), but doesn't go away completely as it tends to come back when I get back to a hotter area.

The first time, it did go away after a while once I got to a cooler area, the second time it lasted until I got something to eat, and then went away almost instantly. What is also weird is that the second time, it only occurred 4-5 hours after the actual run (and I had already eaten and had ample liquids in that time).

I've had someone take my blood pressure and heartbeat when it occurred, but everything was normal on that account.

Could I be having some kind of deficiency, caused by the stress of a running competition? I was thinking something like salt deficiency or iron, although I doubt the last one.

Anyone encounter something similar after heavy exerction?

Sam

Comment: Did you eat and drink enough before you went running?

Comment: I had milk, cereals and raisins about 2 hours before. And there were 3 supply points at which I drank a bit and poured the rest over my head. Directly after the event, I also drank a bottle of sports drink.

Comment: How long did you have to run then, 3 supply points means it was probably a 10 Miles run or something?

Comment: 11km, but fairly high intensity

Comment: Have you experienced any possible effects of overtraining? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/what-are-some-signs-of-overtraining

Comment: Chris, not really. If anything, I tend to undertrain ;)

Comment: Just got a heavy head myself after doing 3 sets of 10 second planks :/ wondered what it was but I'm assuming it's because I didn't eat before the gym? It's not a sore pain but I just feel like my brain is trying to push its way out of my skull :(

Answer (score 2):

While doing high intensity workouts, the blood will rush to your brain and your heartbeats will increase. I think it is not something to worry about, But keep in mind if you are running at really high intensity do not run continuously for 11 kms and all, run to about 1 and a half minutes and then slowly for 2 minutes till heartbeat slows down and then agin sped up, continue this for 10 minutes.

Best OF Luck

Answer (score 2):

I would occasionally get symptoms just like this, for me it was hyperventilation.  I seemed to be breathing harder and deeper than normal, even hours after a run.  I could get rid of the prickly/woozy feeling after breathing in my cupped hands or a paper bag.  Sometimes it would take a few minutes if it was really bad.  Once it happened during a run as I charged up with heavy breathing for a steep hill.  I just slowed my breathing way down and the feeling went away as I climbed the hill.  For prevention, I started practicing breathing exercises and haven't had a problem in years. (Dr Weil's 4-7-8, etc)