# Quick leg workout without equipment

Tags: workout-routines, legs

My friend and I take 5-15 minute breaks every hour while studying.  We like to be productive during these breaks.  Most of the days, we do push-ups during these breaks.  However, on  days when our upper body muscles are sore from push-ups, we'd like to do some sort of quick/easy leg workout.

What's a suggestion for a "push-up like" leg workout that we could do during 5-15 minute breaks without any equipment?

Comment: Squats? Or, if that's too easy, one-legged squats (pistols). If you prefer isometric exercises, you can pushing your back against a wall and bending your knees at a 90 degree angle (sorry, I don't know the name). Hold this as long as possible - it's more challenging than it sounds.

Comment: @VPeric Feel free to post your comment as an answer and explain it more. You can delete the comment (or a mod can) afterwards.

Comment: Find a flight of stairs and get running. You can try [this great 4 step process][proc] to give your legs a quick workout without equipment. [proc]: http://www.livestrong.com/article/176114-how-to-run-up-down-stairs-to-lose-weight/

Answer (score 5):

[Air squats](http://www.fitdaily.com/ExerciseDetail/2), [forward](http://www.acefitness.org/exerciselibrary/94/) and [side lunges](http://www.acefitness.org/exerciselibrary/50/), sprawl, [wall chair](http://www.liveawesome.com/public/365.cfm), and lots and lots of jump rope. (if possible)

Vary it between lots of fast reps and holding in place for 30+ seconds or however long you can stand it.

Do them correctly and **form first**, reps second. You'll majorly mess up knees and back if you do them with bad form.

Comment: The wall chair is an amazingly effective workout but deceptively hard. It is especially good in scenarios like this when you only have a short time to do your workout.

Answer (score 2):

use mark lauren's (a special ops trainer) pistol squat, check this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHyOk0TuXcc)

Most of mark lauren's trainings are "short" timed (max 7 mins) and highly efficient. And From personal experience ( i have been training continuous for 2 years), i never feel my body got "used" to this exercise ie everytime i do the pistol squat, i feel loads of energy, higher adrenaline, my leg muscles keep on growing and I actually feel the pain no matter how many times you have done it before and how many years u have been training.

Its the best short termed/highly efficient leg work out.

Comment: Care to explain why this exercise is so great compared to the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

Rotate through square, lunges and calf raises doing each until you feel a little burn.  If you want, add isometrics.  Sit halfway down in the squat, or make yourself a chair pushing against the wall.  5-15 mins of this repeated over a few hours of studying will do wonders.  Don't forget to stretch too.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the other answers, I can recommend the exercises in [Brungardt - Leg workout](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679754814). Besides a wide array of exercises with/without weights, it contains 12 week programs that has a lot of variation in exercises, difficulty level and time spent.