# How to begin workout after 9 years of no workout?

Tags: workout

I used to workout regularly (long time ago, by going to the gym), but it's about 9 years, I have had no workout or any such activity.

I have put on some weight specially my belly and buttocks. I want to start working out again, and burn the fat. Now I don't know where to begin. Does anyone know a good tutorial/guide where to start?

I know I'd better consult some expert in this field, but here I can find no one! My only hope of finding a guide is internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [question/answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-can-an-overweight-engineer-get-back-in-shape/2058#2058), although not specific to you, gives a good outline for the different aspects of getting back in shape.

For resistance training check out [StrongLifts.com](http://stronglifts.com/).

For aeobic conditioning, [Couch to 5K](http://www.c25k.com/podcasts.htm) has podcasts you can download for a weekly progression.

Diet is also a main concern which I'm sure someone will address.  Best of luck.

Comment: To be honest, my main concern is my buttocks. They have grown too big (and ugly). I would do anything to make them small.

Comment: Sorry, but that comes with losing weight! :)  [Callanetics](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Callanetics.html) targets the right muscles to "shrink and lift" the buttocks.  But to lose weight you need to address your diet and daily activity levels:  cardio with interval training, resistance training for muscles and breaking up prolonged periods of sitting with short breaks.

Comment: You might not believe, but even when I had no extra weight or fat, the buttocks were not normal. They have been big and ugly for as long as I remember.

Comment: You might like callanetics then.  It works the buttocks and core muscles with short, repetitive muscle contractions at the end of range, with visible and measurable results when done regularly.  Good luck finding what works for you.

Comment: Can you please tell me which one should I go with? Quick Hips and Behind?

Comment: The "quick" dvd's are just a shorter version.  If time is your main consideration then quick hips and behind would be good.  Also don't overlook squats, lunges etc. - [other ideas](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/what-can-i-do-to-tone-up-my-bottom).  However, I still think you want to look at getting back in shape in general rather than thinking of spot corrections.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that your primary concern is your weight (specifically belly and buttocks). Now, there is no such thing as targeted weight reduction, so in order to lose weight there you will have to burn it through a regimen of strength training, cardio, and dieting.

## Strength Training

After nine years of relative inactivity, it is fair to say that just about any strength routine is going to give you great results thanks to the novice effect, which states that inactive individuals get in the first few months of training the largest strength gains and results than any other group. In other words, you will see great results simply by picking any routine and sticking to it.

That said, there are some routines that are far better than others and will give you better long-term results, especially with regard to your goals. Among those routines are the [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com) and [Strong Lifts](http://stronglifts.com/) programs, both of which are very highly regarded. **Bonus**: doing squats is awesome for your butt.

## Cardio

For cardio, this is really up to you. As @BackInShapeBuddy said, [Couch to 5k](http://www.c25k.com/) is a popular program for people new to running. If running isn't your thing (I personally hate it) you can swim, bike, hike, play sports, do pylometrics, tae-bo, jazzercise, chase squirrels in the park; really anything works, so be creative and have fun with it.

## Dieting

Finally, there is dieting. While the initial instinct might be to cut down on calories and overall food consumed, that isn't the right approach. You're going to be burning way more energy than you ever have in the last nine years, so eating a lot is important to keep your body fueled. What you need to do is cut out all of the "bad food." Specifically, you need to cut back (better yet, eliminate) empty carbs, highly processed foods, and sugary drinks from your diet. In other words, eat healthy, and make sure you are consuming enough protein to fuel your muscle growth from working out.

Comment: I wish I could mark two posts as the answer. This post is really useful too.