# Is it okay to use a treadmill to lose weight?

Tags: protein-shakes

how long should I wait to exercise after eating Chips and a 32FL Oz Gatorade. My other question what machine should I use to lose a lot of weight?

Comment: Skip the chips and gatorade and start walking/running.  The best mechanism to lose a lot of weight is a proper diet and daily activity.  Diet is not covered on this site.  For exercise, consider [this q/a.](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/how-to-begin-workout-after-9-years-of-no-workout/6220#6220).

Comment: you cant assume that after eating chips and gatorade all the calories will be burned by running in one day.

Answer (score 2):

32FL Oz Gatorade is about 800 calories this equates to between a third and a quarter of your daily calorie intake (depending on your calorie requirements).

**How do you lose a lot of weight?** Stop eating chips and drinking gatorade and start tracking your calorie intake.