# Quadriceps pain after hip bridges excercise

Tags: exercise, muscle-soreness, hip, glutes

I have been doing [hip bridges](http://www.womenshealthmag.com/sites/womenshealthmag.com/files/images/1006-poolside-glute-bridge.jpg) for the last two weeks (I exercise three times a week). I am not  aiming to get a muscular body; I am just training to improve my body shape (I am not that fat).

The problem with the bridges is that, when doing them and trying to raise my hips up, I feel pain in my quadriceps, as if I am targeting the quadriceps and not the glutes. Is this normal?

Indeed, what makes me more confused, is what stated in [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21032/how-to-activate-glutes-on-a-pear/21036#21036). He said:

> What this tells me is that you don't have a strong mind-muscle connection with your glutes. This is called a neuromuscular recruitment pattern, which basically means you use your quads to do most of the work because that's how you've developed. This is really common"

Is this true? If so, am I using only my quads ?

If yes, how to activate my glutes? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know enough to properly answer, but you might look at https://bretcontreras.com/abc-how-can-i-stop-my-hammies-from-taking-over-when-i-perform-barbell-glute-bridges-and-hip-thrusts/ for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "activate" a muscle you need to actively isolate and tense it, that is what "mind-muscle contraction" is (similar to when someone writes the word **kegals** on the internet and the reader will consciously be able to think about and do them. Its that thinking and contracting that is important.

The pain in your quads **may** be due to tight hip flexors, a common issue with bridges. Doing flat foot lunges and other hip-flexor mobility stretches can help.

Just focus on squeezing your ass.